# Trying to issues while using FlatMap

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to learn FlatMap and its usage,  I have an ArrayList as below,

```
ArrayList check = new ArrayList();
check.add("a");
check.add("b");
check.add("c");
ArrayList middleList = new ArrayList();
middleList.add("d");
middleList.add("e");
middleList.add("f");
middleList.add("g");
check.add(middleList);
check.add("h");
check.add("i");
check.add("j");
System.out.println(check);
```

Data will be stored in the below manner:

```
[a, b, c, [d, e, f, g], h, i, j]
```

Now, I am expecting an output as

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j]
```

For which, I have written the below code,

```
System.out.println(check.stream()
        .flatMap(data -> data instanceof ArrayList ? Stream.of(data):data)
        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

**Explanation**: For the arraylist check, I have created a stream object and have invoked flatMap here I am checking if the object is an instance of ArrayList then I intend to create a stream for that arraylist.

It throws ClassCastException not sure where I am going wrong.

**Edit Based on Michael suggestion:**

```
ArrayList<List<String>> check = new ArrayList();
check.add(Arrays.asList("a"));
check.add(Arrays.asList("b"));
check.add(Arrays.asList("c"));
ArrayList middleList = new ArrayList();
middleList.add("d");
middleList.add("e");
middleList.add("f");
middleList.add("g");
check.add(middleList);
check.add(Arrays.asList("h"));
check.add(Arrays.asList("i"));
check.add(Arrays.asList("j"));
System.out.println(check);

List<String> finalResult =check.
        stream().
        flatMap(Collection::stream).
        collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(finalResult);
```

Output: As expected:
[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j]

Comment: Why would you even want a `List<String Or List<String>>`? It would simplify things a lot if you didn't use raw types and didn't treat lists as a bag of junk. I see no reason why you can't just represent your data as a `List<List<String>>`. For the items that are currently just Strings, you can add them as a List of length 1, e.g. `Collections.singletonList("A")`.

Comment: `flatMap` expects mapping to Stream. When `data instanceof ArrayList` you provide mapping to stream created via `Stream.of(data)` (which will represent stream with one element - `data` list itself, not elements *from* that list) BUT when data is NOT instance of ArrayList, like `"a"` your mapping returns that element, not stream holding that element. To solve both problems you may use `flatMap(data -> data instanceof ArrayList ? ((ArrayList) data).stream(): Stream.of(data))` but that still looks like solution to [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) since you are using raw types.

Comment: @Pshemo, I since, I am in the process of learning, I came up with this problem, bad one indeed. If you could update this as an answer, I shall accept it and we can close this thread.

Comment: @User27854 just a suggestion, if you want to just print the contents of the stream, you could use `forEach(System.out::println)` instead of collecting to a list and then printing

Comment: @GauthamM, I intent is to have an understanding of how  flatMap functions/ works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After correcting your original code using typed `ArrayList` and `List` you can do it as follows:

```
List<Object> check = new ArrayList<>();
check.add("a");
check.add("b");
check.add("c");
ArrayList<String> middleList = new ArrayList<>();
middleList.add("d");
middleList.add("e");
middleList.add("f");
middleList.add("g");
check.add(middleList);
check.add("h");
check.add("i");
check.add("j");
System.out.println(check);

List<Object> list = check.stream()
        .flatMap(s -> s instanceof List ?
                ((List<?>) s).stream() : Stream.of(s))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(list);
```

prints

```
[a, b, c, [d, e, f, g], h, i, j]
[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j]
```

`FlatMap` flattens streams so you need to check the type and produce one either by casting the object to a `List<?>` and creating a stream or by creation of a single element stream.  This returns a `List<Object>`.  If you wanted a `List<String>` the other casts and filters would need to be included.

The overall problem doing this is that you have mixed types that don't all lend themselves to `flatMap`. As I can't imagine how this would arise in a production environment I consider it a purely academic exercise.